# How do I git checkout one commit prior to a specific commit

Tags: git

After going through github issues, I've found a commit that *might* be responsible for breaking code and I want to confirm this suspicion by doing something like:

`git checkout --one-prior f1962b3cc771184a471e1350fa280d80d5fdd09d`

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

Comment: May also be worth looking at `git bisect` for hunting down breaking changes: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html

Comment: Chris thanks for reminding me to learn how that `git bisect` magic works

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here you go:

```
git checkout f1962b3cc771184a471e1350fa280d80d5fdd09d^
```

Notice the `^` at the end. That means one revision behind.

For example this would be 5 revisions behind:

```
git checkout f1962b3cc771184a471e1350fa280d80d5fdd09d^^^^^
```

... equivalent to:

```
git checkout f1962b3cc771184a471e1350fa280d80d5fdd09d~5
```

Btw, when you do this, you'll be in a *detached HEAD* state. The output explains this, which is very interesting and worth reading:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
>   may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
>   Example:
>
> ```
>     git checkout -b new_branch_name
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question for a `checkout`, but you can also use `rebase` instead.

Here is a short log of my terminal history without working it over.

```sh
Rebase to change first the second last and then the last commit
 1240  git rebase -i HEAD~2 
→ then an editor pops up, write “edit” in front of the commit you 
want to change (in my case the older commit, look up the commit msg 
in the git repo to find the right one), leave the other at “pick”
 1241  git rev-parse HEAD 
→ shows the hash, better use `git log`, then you do not need to 
remember the hashes!
 1242  git add .
 1243  git status
 1244  git commit --amend
 1245  git rebase --continue
 1246  git rev-parse HEAD
 1247  git reflog
 1248  git rebase -i HEAD~2
→ then an editor pops up, write “edit” in front of the commit you 
want to change (in my case the younger commit, look up the commit msg 
in the git repo to find the right one), leave the other at “pick”
 1249  git rev-parse HEAD
 1250  git log
 1251  git status
 1252  git add .
 1253  git commit --amend
 1254  git rebase --continue
 1255  git log
 1256  git push -f
 1257  git log
```